# Java - Deferent between declare class and class object (class vs class)

Tags: java, class

Please see below code and say me what is deferent.

```
public class c1
{
  //....
}

Class c2 = obj.getClass();

Object o1 = new c1();
Object o2 = new c2();  //  <<-----  here
```

Whats wrong end line ???

How i can to create a object of c2 ????

Edit:

```
int[] s1 = new int[]{4,5,6};
char[] s2 = new char[]{'a'.'b'};

Integer[] new = convertPrimitiveArrayToObject(new Object[]{s1});
Character[] new = convertPrimitiveArrayToObject(new Object[]{s2});


public static <T> T[] convertPrimitiveArrayToObject(Object[] primitive)
    {
           Object x =  primitive[0];
            Class type = x.getClass().getComponentType();  // => int OR char
            type[] x2 = (type[]) x;         // I need to convert array to (int/char/...)

      //......
   }
```

Comment: Are you expecting to be able to `new c2` after you `obj.getClass()`?

Comment: `c2` isn't class. It is an object of Class type.

Comment: For parameter `Object[] primitive` you cannot pass any `int[]` or `char[]` array. Maybe you should provide an example of what you want to achieve.

Comment: [For parameter Object[] primitive you cannot pass any int[] or char[] array. Maybe you should provide an example of what you want to achieve]
Yes .for this i set int[] to a object. Note to ( convertPrimitiveArrayToObject(new Object[]{s1}) )

Answer (score 1):

You need to use reflection , read first Java Reflection

This will help you
[Creating New Class Instances](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/ctorInstance.html)

**Creating Object**

```
Object object = null;
  try {
      Class clazz = Class.forName("yor fully qualified class name");
      object = clazz.newInstance();
  } catch (InstantiationException e) {
      System.out.println(e);
  } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
      System.out.println(e);
  } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
      System.out.println(e);
  }
```

Comment: I am sorry.I am Iranian.in Iran can not access to this site,this site prohibition my country, please help me

Comment: No,I not need to new instance,i want to convert a array that is inside a object to a array,but i not know class of that array,my method get(receive) (int,char,boolean,long and other primitive as array )inside a object

Answer (score 0):

```
Object o2 = (C1) c2.newInstance();
```

Comment: No No, c1 was a sample only.